# Promise stuck at pending when downloading from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a firebase database formatted like this (Where the random numbers/letters are the uid of the user):

```
profile
     kLZwdaWYEdAJ3cPk
         user_dict
questions
     category
         some other words
     another category
         some more words
```

user_dict is an object stored with their profile information that I need to download before the app continues.

This is the code I'm using to retrieve it:

```
function getUserDict() {
    let current_user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    return firebase.database().ref().child('profile').child(current_user_id).child('user_dict').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val()
    })
}
```

Immediately after this function I call `console.log('userLogin user_dict is', user_dict)` which has a value of `Promise {<pending>}` while the app hangs. I'm assuming there's an issue with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns a `Promise`, you need to either `await` it or use `then` similar to how you have done in the method itself

```
(async function test(){
    const user_dict = await getUserDict();
    console.log('userLogin user_dict is', user_dict);
})();
```

or

```
getUserDict().then(user_dict => console.log('userLogin user_dict is', user_dict));
```

Comment: Thanks but neither methods are working for me. I uploaded my two attempts as well as my getUserDict function on a code share site because I can't figure out a way to share it on StackOverflow here since there's a 500 character limit.

http://ronsoros.github.io/?bcd8fa220cec2a0c3a38bc6e7469c48471ccb120

Comment: if (is_first_time) {
        hideInputText()
        user_dict = getQuestions().then(user_dict => console.log('handleWelcome user_dict is ', user_dict))
        is_user_dict = true
        right_button.innerText = "Next"
        right_button.onclick = handleFirstTime1
    }

Comment: It returns user_dict is null, though my getQuestions function normally works fine meaning it has to be an issue with the promise. getQuestions normally edits a global var user_dict, but I also had it return user_dict since it wasn't working so I thought maybe returning the value would help keep the promise from continuing too early.

Comment: I figured out the problem, I was passing the wrong conditional variable and was triggering an almost identical function. Didn't notice until I debugged line by line, sorry. I'm marking the answer correct, it's working fine now.